# Choosing particular records from a result set depending on value

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query that attempts to compile a report of charges and credits, grouped by Item codes and billing period.  The Charge table that it pulls from has the following format:

```
BillingPeriod|ItemCode|ItemName|Charge|IsAdjustment|AdjustmentDate|ReportTimestamp
```

I have run into a few problems that my current query handles pretty nicely, I think.  Since some of the times the billing code does not occur in the charge table, because we weren't billed for it, yet I want a uniform table that displays each billing period, so I make a dummy table filled with billing periods and zeroes, and Union that with the results from the Charges table, like this:

```
SELECT BillingPeriod, SumOfCharge AS Total FROM (
        SELECT BillingPeriod, 0 AS SumOfCharge
        FROM Charges
        UNION
        SELECT BillingPeriod, SUM(Charge) AS SumOfCharge
        FROM Charges
        WHERE (ItemCode Between 1900 and 1995)
        GROUP BY BillingPeriod
);
```

So what ends up happening is this: Say, for instance, I have one charge for January and March of 2011 but nothing else.  The table will return output like this:

```
BillingPeriod|Charge
1/1/2011     |100.00
1/1/2011     |0
2/1/2011     |0
3/1/2011     |0
3/1/2011     |-23.00
4/1/2011     |0
5/1/2011     |0
6/1/2011     |0
7/1/2011     |0
```

What I'm trying to do is get rid of those 0-valued rows and select the correct one to display in the report.  The only tricky part is that the values could be positive, negative, or zero so just doing MAX won't work.  I also tried FIRST() or LAST(), (COALESCE()) doesn't work, I'm in access).  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just sum up the `SumOfCharge` field and group by `BillingPeriod`:

```
SELECT BillingPeriod, SUM(SumOfCharge) AS Total FROM (
    SELECT BillingPeriod, 0 AS SumOfCharge
    FROM Charges
    UNION
    SELECT BillingPeriod, SUM(Charge) AS SumOfCharge
    FROM Charges
    WHERE (ItemCode Between 1900 and 1995)
    GROUP BY BillingPeriod
) GROUP BY BillingPeriod;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
SELECT P.BillingPeriod, 
ISNULL(C.SumOfCharge,0) AS SumOfCharge
FROM (
    SELECT Distinct BillingPeriod
    FROM Charges) AS P
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT BillingPeriod, SUM(Charge) AS SumOfCharge
    FROM Charges
    WHERE (ItemCode Between 1900 and 1995)
    GROUP BY BillingPeriod) as C
ON P.BillingPeriod = C.BillingPeriod
ORDER BY P.BillingPeriod
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work:

```
SELECT C.BillingPeriod,
       ISNULL(C1.SumOfCharge, 0) AS Total
FROM Charges
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT BillingPeriod, SUM(Charge) AS SumOfCharge
                 FROM Charges
                 WHERE (ItemCode Between 1900 and 1995)
                 GROUP BY BillingPeriod) C1 ON C.BillingPeriod = C1.BillingPeriod
```